# Execution failed for task ':sqflite:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

I am trying to run a flutter app but I am getting this error. It only gets resolved when I remove cached network image dependency from pubspec.yaml file.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Redmi Note 9 Pro in debug
mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                     
// Stack Trace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sqflite:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 42s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            224.1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

From various answers I was able to deduce that there's problem with something called gradle :

```
➜  android git:(arjun/mar20/search_bar) ✗ ./gradlew --version

Welcome to Gradle 6.5!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Experimental file-system watching
 - Improved version ordering
 - New samples

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/release-notes.html


------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.5
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-06-02 20:46:21 UTC
Revision:     a27f41e4ae5e8a41ab9b19f8dd6d86d7b384dad4

Kotlin:       1.3.72
Groovy:       2.5.11
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          13.0.7 (Private Build 13.0.7+5-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04)
OS:           Linux 5.4.0-146-generic amd64
```

This is the java version

```
➜  android git:(arjun/mar20/search_bar) ✗ java -version
openjdk version "16.0.1" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 16.0.1+9-Ubuntu-120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.1+9-Ubuntu-120.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

added this in build.gradle file :

```
 compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
```

Can anybody please explain why its happening and how can I resolve this?